# jQuery Autocomplete json same result

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have this code in ***index.php***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
source: "getResults.php"
});
```

and ***getResults.php*** contains:

```
<?php
$result = array();
array_push($result, "Apple");
array_push($result, "Banana");
array_push($result, "Orange");
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Why do I keep getting same results?

Whatever I type inside the searchInput I get same list / result,

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly what do you hope to accomplish? `$result` will ALWAYS contain the 3 values you're pushing. Do you expect those to change? Maybe your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: @TonyM, I want to get to a situation where I start typing the first letters of the word "Ap..", to get only Apple from $result, exactly like this example here pastebin.com/SnyhvpXc , I'm not sure how much this related to php , it should be jQuery/Javascript thing to filter contents, I'm not willing to post anything to the php file, i'm just trying to get result from php file, while  the result should be filtered as i'm typing..

Comment: Are you getting all 3 even when you've typed "Ap" ? Just tried your setup exactly as is on my local environment and it works fine.

Comment: @TonyM , yes exactly, that what I was trying to say :(

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not sending "Whatever is submitted into the php script"

You only have this data:

```
<?php
$result = array();
array_push($result, "Apple");
array_push($result, "Banana");
array_push($result, "Orange");
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

That is all you'll get.

You need to check `$_POST` and push the post content into the array

UPDATE

Since you mentioned in the comments you want to show auto suggest, you need to do something like this.

```
//php file

if($_POST && isset($_POST['keyword']){
  $search = $_POST['keyword']; 
  $array =  ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']; 

  foreach($array as $fruit){
    if(strpos($search, $fruit) === 0){
      echo $fruit; 
    }
  }
}
```

You can send the word to this php file via ajax as POST request.

Comment: but it is not the case with this example,  https://pastebin.com/SnyhvpXc , how is it different?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But the value will not change, because you are not sending anything to your PHP code, so nothing will change. Maybe if you could tell me what you want to do that might help

Comment: I'm not willing to post anything to the php. Simply, I'm trying to get different results from a php file, and yes i'm getting them, my question is why the autocomplete javascript function doesn't filter the "Already / Loaded " content by itself? I mean look at the website  pastebin.com/SnyhvpXc , as you see there if you run that script the variable  availableTags has many values, and still it works when you try to search a specific value, it shows you only that value, not all values,

Comment: OP is reading the content of the PHP file, not writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I see a missing bracket in your JS, I hope you have that set up correctly on your end:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchInput").autocomplete({
  source: "getResults.php"
});
```

Should be:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchInput").autocomplete({
      source: "getResults.php"
    });
});
```

Edit:

Since you're getting data from another file, you need to follow the instructions here:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

This walks you through calling the php file.

Comment: it seems a good tutorial there, but I cannot find the search.php source code,